# matplotlib interactive mode: determine if figure window is still displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib in interactive mode to show the user a plot that will help them enter a range of variables. They have the option of hitting "?" to show this plot, and the prompt for variables will then be repeated.

How do I know to not re-draw this plot if it's still being displayed?

Superficially, I have this clunky (pseudo-ish) code:

```
answer = None
done_plot = False
while answer == None:
    answer = get_answer()
    if answer == '?':
        if done_plot:
            have_closed = True
            ##user's already requested a plot - has s/he closed it?
            ## some check here needed:
            have_closed = ?????

            if have_closed == False:
                print 'You already have the plot on display, will not re-draw'
                answer = None
                continue
        plt.ion()
        fig = plt.figure()
        ### plotting stuff
        done_plot = True
        answer = None
    else:
        ###have an answer from the user...
```

what can I use (in terms of plt.gca(), fig etc...) to determine if I need to re-plot? Is there a status somewhere I can check?

Many thanks,

David

Comment: Think it needs more clarity in the question. Do you keep track of the figures they have opened? Can there be multiple figures at once or just one figure open?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the same vein as unutbu's answer, you can also check whether a given figure is still opened with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if plt.fignum_exists(<figure number>):
    # Figure is still opened
else:
    # Figure is closed
```

The figure number of a figure is in `fig.number`.

PS: Note that the "number" in `figure(num=…)` can actually be a string: it is displayed in the window title. However, the figure still has a `number` attribute which is numeric. The original *string* `num` value can however be used with `fignum_exists()` (since 2015, according to Mark H, in the comments).

PPS: That said, `subplots(…, num=<string num>)` properly recovers the existing figure with the given *string* number. Thus, figures are still known by their string number in some parts of Matplotlib.

Comment: Just a note, you can acquire the number with `fig.number` like in `plt.fignum_exists(fig.number)`.

Comment: However, when I create a figure by `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)` and having not yet displayed it, the output of `plt.fignum_exists(fig.number)` is `True`. Shouldn't it be `False`?

Comment: A figure does not have to be displayed in order to exist: it is in essence an _internal_ representation of some graphics. Often the graphics is displayed, but sometimes it is not: a simple example is when the figure is being created as a PDF file. It thus makes sense to have access to the figure even when nothing is displayed (one could for instance want to switch between multiple figures with `plt.figure(num=…)` before any of the figures is complete).

Comment: In interactive mode, I don't seem to be able to close the window. When I press the button to close it (the one in the top right corner with a cross on it), nothing happens. How can I make sure the window is closed when I press the x?

Comment: Also, when I resize the plot window, the plot is not redrawn, but maybe it's supposed to be like that. Anyway, it would be also nice if the picture was redrawn when the window was resized. Do you know why it's not and how that can be achieved?

Comment: I solved it; I just needed to call [`matplotlib.pyplot.pause`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html) so that the GUI event loop is run; this solver both of my issues.

Comment: Update: Since 2015, a `str` figure label can be used with `fignum_exists()`, not just a number.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer (whose last edit dated back to 2014!).

Answer (score 24):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if plt.get_fignums():
    # window(s) open
else:
    # no windows
```

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.get_fignums()` does nearly the same thing without the additional import.